# Css transition from opacity 0 to 1 back to 0

Tags: css, transition

I have a div element, which I have initially kept at Zero '0' opacity.
On certain event I add a class with transition 0.3s and opacity '1'.
But I want transition to to end on out immediately (set 0 opacity without transition when class is removed).

```
div{
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
div:hover{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Tried only with ease-in, and also cubic-bezier(), but somehow I can't do it.

Comment: Specify the transition for that class only.

Comment: _“I want transition to happen during 'ease-in', meaning from”_ - no, that is not what `ease-in` means to begin with.

Comment: When class is removed it is taking 0.3s to fade out, I want it to end immediately.

Comment: And that’s why I said, specify transition for that class only. (Your example doesn’t use a class, but it works the same way for the pseudo-class :hover.)

Comment: Just move your transition to 'hover' state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your transition to 'hover' state.

```css
    div{
       opacity: .5;
    }
    div:hover{
       opacity: 1;
       transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
    }
```

```html
<div>hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```css
div {   
  height:150px; width:150px; background:red;
  opacity: 0;
}

div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
Put cursor below
<div></div>
```